# Get a list of all parameters in Command Line for Start Command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to print out all the arguments that exist in a program in WINDOWS COMMAND LINE.

What I did so far and is working:

```
start C:\Program Files\Soft\MySoftware.exe "/Launch:Prod;SessionName 5.21.45.23"
```

The problem is the number in the end, that `5.21.45.23` because is changing once a week or two(is a version number of something).

I tried to put wildcards `"*"` instead of that number but is not working because the arguments for `start` command are static.

```
start C:\Program Files\Soft\MySoftware.exe "/Launch:Prod;SessionName *"
```

I was thinking to print out all the args possible in a list and select my arg. Or to pass that version number somehow to open the program.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: "exist in a program"? I don't understand this. Does this mean all the batch file arguments?

Comment: "/Launch:Prod;SessionName 5.21.45.23" is what is running by the .exe program

Comment: Do you call the batch file with some text?

Comment: Yes the code in the post is all I have in the batch file, and I want to use a wildcard for that number because is dynamic